# Data security by third party esta suppliers

Tags: privacy, credit-card

Unfortunately I have required the ESTA (The Electronic System for Travel Authorization) on a [non-official website](https://www.estausa.com/), which ask me a very high fee, with respect to the [official website](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov) where it costs only 14$. I have immediately wrote the this website asking to cancel my request and refund me. Surprizing they did it, I got a refund.

Now my point is: what about the data I have gave to them. It seems to me that these people what to cheat people, so I am worried about what they are going to use with my data, including personal data and credit card (including cvv). Should I be worried? Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a discussion (in french language) [here](https://www.cnewyork.net/2016/06/13/esta-faux-sites-officiels/). What is said is that there are many sites that require more that the official fee *for their help* in getting the document, which is allowed. And a comment say that generally they do not do more harm than the additional fee, because it is enough for them to live and passing *fraudulous* operation would come at the risk of being legally attacked.

So you should just control your account statements and if you see a fraudulous operation, just require your bank to cancel it - what you should anyway already do. At least in France, every bank immediately cancel any payment if it is declared as fraudulous unless it has been confirmed by the pincode, a manually signed paper or a 2FA method like a SMS code.

So unless your bank declare that you must prove that an operation is fraudulous for them to cancel it (and my advice would be to change your bank), you should not worry too much about you data. After all, it would not be that different than an evil employee on a good site, because he could also steal the informations.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an account on a website you always should try to find out if this website is trustworthy. So my advice, if you are not sure just don't create an account. If you decide to create one, see if you can give in as less personal data as possible. Fake the data that you can. So giving sites you don't trust your credit card data might not be a good idea. If the website has malicious intents or your cvv is leaked from the website, the cvv could be used as a verification means to obtain access to other websites / online services you use. (the technique used is called social engineering). When it comes to credit cards, the only thing you can do to exclude potential risk is request a new one. But you should do this only if you have a good reason to do so.